# Mysql, Issue with inserting a row into a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I've inserted many rows into tables before in the past but this particular instance keeps giving me an error and I can't figure out why. I've restarted mysql/tried disabling foreign key checks and etc but it still fails.

Here is my insert command:

```
insert into subreddits_subreddit(name, desc, admin_id) values('firstSubreddit', 
      'This is a test.', 1)
```

My error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that c   
orresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, admin_id) 
values('firstSubreddit', 'This is a test.', 1)' at line 1
```

Here is the schema for subreddits_subreddit.

```
subreddits_subreddit | CREATE TABLE `subreddits_subreddit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `user_id` (`admin_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `subreddits_subreddit_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES 
          `users_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Here is the users table which it references:

```
 users_user | CREATE TABLE `users_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

The users_user table has one row inside it with an id value of 1, so the user FK reference should be ok. The subreddits_subreddit table is empty (I just made it)

Any ideas on what to do? Thank you.

Comment: You did not post the error, but I'm guessing it is something like "check the manual for the correct syntax to use near 'desc`, right?  If so, that's because `DESC` is a reserved keyword requiring backticks to be used as a column name.

Comment: Wow you are right, http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50883

Comment: This is the official list [of reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Accept whatever you get below. I don't need it and we have a number of these with the exact error searchable already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`desc` is a keyword for use with order by and whatnot

Escape `desc` by putting backtick magic quotes:

```
insert into subreddits_subreddit(name, `desc`, admin_id)
  values('firstSubreddit', 'This is a test.', 1)
```